# HTML setting table height to 100%

Tags: asp.net, html, css, height

I’ve tried doing this, but it seems to just be ignored.  I found a few articles saying that if you wanted to do this then you had to make sure that the parent object was also 100%.  I have the following:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server" style="height:100%">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <style type="text/css">
      .MasterStyle
      {
          width: 98%;            
          height: 100%;
      }
      .ContentStyle
      {         
          width: 100%;
      }
      .TableStyle
      {
          width: 133px;                     
          height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
 </head>
 <body class="MasterStyle">
    <form id="frmMaster" runat="server">
     <div class="ContentStyle">        
      <asp:Label runat="server" Text="My Site Name" Font-Bold="true" Font-Names="MS-Sans" 
            Style="text-align:right" Width="100%" />
      <br />        
    </div>
    <hr />
    <table style="width:100%; height:100%" border="true">
      <tr>
        <td class="TableStyle" style="height:100%">
```

I have a border around the table and can see that it’s not filling the height.  Can anyone tell me why I’m not getting 100% height?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is also browser dependant, the implementations vary a little bit...
But try setting `<html>` to a height of 100 % as well, since it is the element surrounding `<body>`. The hierarchy is `html` > `body` > `table`, if the outermost element is not set to 100%, the inner ones can not get any bigger.

**Edit:**
Looking closer at your source code, I believe that your table is actually sitting at `html` > `body` > `form` > `table`, so maybe you nee  to set the form height to 100 %, too. And I noticed that your `<head>` is set to 100 %, better remove that, since `<head>` is not part of the hierarchy of your table. You  never how setting a height for `<head>` might confuse a rendering engine...

Comment: Thanks.  Setting the form and html worked.  However, I get a compile warning saying that there is no style property of html!